# Ayuda sobre diseño de base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos

Buenos días, me encuentro desarrollando un sistema en donde se debe agregar un ítem con múltiples variantes, las variantes son dinámicas se puede agregar desde una hasta cuatro variantes, cada variante tiene sus datos de entrada, los datos deben ser guardados en una base de datos, como en la imagen de ejemplo, el problema es que no encuentro una forma adecuada de diseñar la base de datos, ya que tanto el ítem, como sus variantes deben visualizarse al momento que un usuario lo requiera, agradezco la ayuda sobre ideas o consejos de como lograr realizar esta parte, el motor de base de datos que estoy usando es mysql muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La base de datos tiene que guardar los datos eficientemente para su recuperacion/insercion, la vista en la aplicacion no tiene nada que ver a como guardar los datos.

Comment: Necesito crear la relación entre el ítem y sus variantes, para después mostrarlos en la vista, creo que si tiene que ver, ya que si guardo los datos de forma incorrecta, al momento de recuperarlos depronto se me genera un problema mayor.

Comment: no. Los datos se guardan de la forma que sea necesario para que la base de datos quede en tercera forma normal, lo menos redundante y veloz que se pueda. Si esto es un datawarehouse, entonces podemos hablar de otras reglas. Lo es? Si no, la vista no tiene nada que ver con la forma de guardar los datos. Y en su defecto, habra vistas (de la base de datos), para acelerar las recuperaciones. O triggers que actualicen otras tablas. Igual, es una pregunta que si no arreglamos con reglas claras, es muy basada en opiniones.

Comment: Quizás no lograste entender mi pregunta, solo quiero diseñar la base de datos de tal forma que el ítem esté relacionado con sus variantes, si realizo mal el diseño voy a tener problemas al momento de visualizar los datos, estoy hablando del diseño de la base de datos, mas no el diseño visual de la aplicación, agradezco su ayuda si tiene alguno consejo sobre el tema, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Andrews Lo que puedes hacer es que estén relacionados con Ítems, mediante una relación opcional, esto quiere decir que en el resto de detalles debe permitir null cuando no registres en esas tablas.

Comment: variante es para todos igual? o sea el item 1 variante 1 tiene los mismos datos de variante que el item 2 variante 1?

Comment: @Pedro Ávila por ejemplo creo el item Camisa con sus características: Nombre, Valor etc, pero al item Camisa deseo agregarle una variante: Tipo, esta variante también tiene sus características: Talla, Color  y cantidad disponibles de esta variante, pero adicionalmente deseo agregar otra variante ya que hay la misma camisa pero con otro color y otra talla y otras cantidades y así sucesivamente se le agregan variantes de acuerdo al item, no se como relacionar esto de tal forma que me quede sencillo recuperar los datos, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @Andrews El negocio vende solo ropa?

Comment: No, los items no están definidos ya que son muchos, por eso en el sistema a cada variante el usuario le agrega de forma manual el nombre y la descripción, pueden ser desde camisas, celulares, juguetes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es un relacion simple. Salvo que algo no este bien explicado, tenes una relacion muchos a muchos entre dos tablas.

La forma de relacionarlos es con una tabla intermedia que pivotee y una las dos tablas, de esa forma, la relacion pasa a ser 0..n entre las tablas...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un item puede tener de 0 a n variantes.. y lo mismo pasa con las variantes..

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, precisamente debía agregar una tabla intermedia tal como dices, muchas gracias.